# __cdecl _unlock has problems with VS C++ 2010 when declare a point to pointer's point throw thread error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred  in mlock. c at __cdecl _unlock()  function.

My code is below 
`

```
void Compute_AB(double *gpos,double **x, double *nv,double **ds,double ***a,double ***b,int mm2,int nx, int ndex)
 {
//!------------------------------------------------------------------
//! Compute A matrix and B matrix and their derivatives
//! input--gpos,x,nv,dm,nx,numnode,ndex,mm
//! output--a,b
//! From 1 to 10 of the third dimension of a denotes
//!    a,dax,day,daxx,daxy,dayy, dadxxx,dadxxy,dadxyy,dadyyy
//! From 1 to 10 of the third dimension of b denotes
//!    b,dbx,dby,dbxx,dbxy,dbyy,dbdxxx,dbdxxy,dbdxyy,dbdyyy
//!----------------------------------------------------------------

 double **w;
 int numnode=ndex;
 double **p=new double*[6];
 for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
 {p[i]=new double[ndex];
 for (int j=0;j<ndex;j++)
 p[i][j]=0.0;
 }
 //inintial pp
 double ***pp=new double**[numnode];
 for(int i=0;i<numnode;i++)
 {


 pp[i]=new double*[mm2];
 for(int j=0;j<mm2;j++)
{    pp[i][j]=new double[mm2];
 /*for(int k=0;k<mm2;k++)
     pp[i][j][k]=0.0;*/}
 }
 //initial diff;
 double **dif;

    dif=new double*[nx];

    for(int i=0;i<nx;i++)
    {
        dif[i]=new double[ndex];
        for(int j=0;j<ndex;j++)
        {
        dif[i][j]=0.0;
          //std::cout<<dif[i][j]<<", " ;
        }
         //std::cout<<std::endl;*/
    }
    //end initial
    //////////////////////////////////
    //initial **w
    w=new double*[numnode];
    for (int i=0;i<numnode;i++)
{
    w[i]=new double[10];
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
        w[i][j]=0.0;


}

        // initial xv
        double **xv=new double*[nx];
        for(int j=0;j<nx;j++)
            xv[j]=new double[numnode];

        //////////////////////////////////
        ///         INITIAL P


     for(int i=0;i<ndex;i++){
         int nn;
         nn=int(nv[i]);
         xv[0][i]=x[0][nn];
         xv[1][i]=x[1][nn];

p[0][i]=1.0;
p[1][i]=xv[0][i];
p[2][i]=xv[1][i];
p[3][i]=xv[0][i]*xv[0][i];
p[4][i]=xv[0][i]*xv[1][i];
p[5][i]=xv[1][i]*xv[1][i];
         dif[0][i]=gpos[0]-xv[0][i];
         dif[1][i]=gpos[1]-xv[1][i];

     }



     ///////////////////////// end initial
    /*mexPrintf("out w before calculation:\n");
for(int i=0;i<ndex;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
    mexPrintf("%g  ",w[i][j]);
mexPrintf("\n");
}*/

Weight_W1(dif,nv,ds,w,ndex);// another function, it works as a single function

// ************* Compute b and its derivatives

      for(int ii=0;ii<mm2;ii++)
      {  for( int jj=0;jj<ndex;jj++)
         {  for(int kk=0;kk<10;kk++)
              { b[ii][jj][kk]=p[ii][jj]*w[jj][kk];
      }

      }

      }

      // display B

// ************* Compute a and its derivatives
      for(int ie=0;ie<mm2;ie++)
         for(int je=0;je<mm2;je++)
           for(int ke=0;ke<10;ke++)
           {     a[ie][je][ke]=0.0;}




           for(int iii=0;iii<ndex;iii++)
         {  for(int ik=0;ik<mm2;ik++){
        for(int jk=0;jk<mm2;jk++ )
        {pp[iii][ik][jk]=p[ik][iii]*p[jk][iii] ;

           }

           }

           }

        for(int iii=0;iii<ndex;iii++)
       for(int ikk=0;ikk<mm2;ikk++)
           for(int jkk=0;jkk<mm2;jkk++)
            for(int kkk=0;kkk<10;kkk++)
            {
                  a[ikk][jkk][kkk]=a[ikk][jkk][kkk]+w[iii][kkk]*pp[iii][ikk][jkk];
           }

       for(int ikk=0;ikk<mm2;ikk++)
           {for(int jkk=0;jkk<mm2;jkk++)
            {for(int kkk=0;kkk<10;kkk++)
            {




            }

       }


       }


}`
```

errors occurs when the code run to

```
double ***pp=new double**[numnode];
 for(int i=0;i<numnode;i++)
 {


 pp[i]=new double*[mm2];
 for(int j=0;j<mm2;j++)
{    pp[i][j]=new double[mm2];
 /*for(int k=0;k<mm2;k++)
     pp[i][j][k]=0.0;*/}
 }
```

numnode=47092; mm2=3, nx=2; ndex=numnode2

Helps. Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is not a 'please fix all my code' site, please at least leave out all those useless comments and make the code readable and properly formatted - http://sscce.org/ . On a sidenote, if a human being can barely read this code, how do you expect a compiler/linker to make a working program out of it?

Comment: what @stijn said. It seems like you ran into some memory allocation or access problem, possibly related to multithreading while executing some unmanaged C++ from managed code. You are allocating at least 47092*3 little chunks on the heap. If you know that you are going to allocate larger chunks of memory you should try to allocate it in one chunk (or at least fewer larger chunks) to minimize the heap management overhead.

The error itself doesn't seem to lie in the piece of code you highlighted at the end alone, so it seems to have to do with what you did with the runtime around that code.

Comment: Thanks ofr stijn and PeterT. The code runs pretty good if numnode =100; maybe it's not quite readable , but it does works correctly. I have validated the results with numnode =100. I am interested in PeterT's suggestions. One of my friend also points out it may relative to thread issue. But in fact this program is designed as a single thread one. And I have changed several computer to run it every time it breaks as the code I mentioned at the end . Could Peter give more suggestions. In the main code I use istream to read in a file but would it matter?

Comment: @Jane I'd use less allocations, you need to use less `new`. If you want a `double[47092][3][3]` you can get it in a contiguous piece of memory by just writing `int dim1=47092;int dim2=3;int dim3=3; double *ppp = new double[dim1*dim2*dim3];` then you can access it by writing `ppp[i*dim2*dim3 + j *dim3 + k]` instead of `ppp[i][j][k]`. Be aware that this is more C than C++ style-wise and idiomatic C++ would look quite different.

Comment: Appreciate PeterT’s suggestions. You are right. What I need to do is just turn a large number of small chunks into a large chunk. That means I have use a 1D pointer to replace the 3D pointer pp, and now it works perfect. I hope stack flow can keep this poster for the new beginners like me to solve similar problem

Comment: Peter answer my question I would like to comment u XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really try to heed what @stijn said. Also, regarding readability and self-documentation of code.

Anyway, pertaining to your question, the problem appears to be that you allocate too many little pieces of memory on the heap in the VC++ runtime. You'd have to look into the memory allocation code to see how this error actually occurred. So, the problem is with the runtime environment you use and its implementation and not the C++ standard itself.

Without understanding the underlying cause 100% you can allocate one contiguous array containing all of the elements of the multi-dimensional array instead to avoid this from happening.

So,

```
int numnode = 47092;
int mm2 = 3;
double ***pp=new double**[numnode];
for(int i=0;i<numnode;i++)
{
    pp[i]=new double*[mm2];
    for(int j=0;j<mm2;j++)
    {
        pp[i][j]=new double[mm2];
        for(int k=0;k<mm2;k++)
            pp[i][j][k]=0.0;}
}
```

can be re-written as

```
int dim1 = 47092;
int dim2 = 3;
int dim3 = 3;
double *arr=new double[dim1*dim2*dim3];
```

then access it with

```
arr[i*dim2*dim3 + j*dim3 + k];
//in place of pp[i][j][k];
```

Be aware that this is not very idiomatic of modern C++ and is stylistically closer to C than C++ but then again, so is the rest of your code.